# How can I extract proxy ip address using C# regex

Tags: c#, regex, ip

I want to extract a proxy address (both host and port) from a string by using C# regex.
The string looks like this:

```
<span class="tbBottomLine" style="width:140px;">
            208.31.251.38
        </span>
        <span class="tbBottomLine" style="width:50px;">
                80
        </span>
```

or this

```
<tr class="odd">
<td>115.29.247.115</td>
<td>8888</td></tr>
```

Comment: Looks like a job for a parser instead....

Comment: Are you trying to parse html...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to write a regex, wich wil capture a proxy info from any markup. For example some websites can "bake" port number into a picture, so you have to process each kind of markup individually.

In general, **html cannot and should not be parsed with RegEx**.

Anyway, here's an example wich can process both of you input strings

```
WebProxy[] ProxyArray = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<ip>\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*).*?>\s*(?<port>\d+)\s*<")
               .Cast<Match>().Select(m => new WebProxy(m.Groups["ip"].Value + ":" + m.Groups["port"].Value)).ToArray();
```

Remember, entire code of the page can contain elements which will broke this RegEx down.

You probably want to take a look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).